# Adding a bounty to a very senior question

Tags: discussion, bounties

I just came across a bounty added to an old question on SO. That question has hundreds of upvotes and stars, nearly 100K views and an accepted answer with a score of over 1K.

Why would someone put a bounty on such a question? It's highly unlikely that anyone, save the person who posted the bounty, will even scroll down enough to *see* any new answers, never mind upvote them after having read the accepted answer (which has had tons of edits and is a real gem, as you probably won't be surprised to hear).

Is there something I 'm missing here?

Comment: Could you show us the question?

Comment: @JeremyBanks: I thought that maybe it would be better to keep the discussion abstract, but it's [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/plain-english-explanation-of-big-o) if you want to take a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bounties are also often used to "tip" users that provide help one needs.  For instance, I had a problem I thought I'd have to ask a new question for, but found not only an existing question, but an answer that so thouroughly resolved my issue that I wanted to give more than just one upvote.  So I applied a bounty and awarded it later.

Comment: That makes sense. Does the bounty count even if the answer is CW?

Comment: @Jon: [Yes, it does.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is that someone posted the bounty in an attempt to prevent the question from getting closed. Close votes cannot be cast while a bounty is in effect.

Moderators can refund and cancel bounties, though, so it only works for protection against closures by community.

Looking at [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/plain-english-explanation-of-big-o), it looks like [Adam Davis' theory](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105372/adding-a-bounty-to-a-very-senior-question/105373#105373) is more likely. The question is a community wiki now, so upvotes do not award reputation. It seems that the bounty owner wanted to reward the poster with some reputation and did so with a bounty.